# C# one list with various object types

Tags: c#, oop

I am new to C#, for a school assignment we need to create a C# class that represents a solar system, I have a class of

```
namespace Schoolwork456S2
{
    public class SolarSystem
    {
        public int Radius { get; set; }

        public SolarSystem(int radius)
        {
            this.Radius = radius;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to have class objects for planets, sun, astroid belts and human vehicles like Vogager.  How do I create a list that can hold all of them, if that is possible?  My teacher hinted at interfaces, but I don't get how that would work.

Thank you

Comment: You have two options: create a List of `object`s or make all your objects inherit from a base class/interface.

Comment: As indicated by your teacher, create an [Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) and name it `ISpaceObject` (or something similar), create the classes for each of the space objects you mentioned and [implement the interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/implement-interface) in each one of them, and then in your `SolarSystem` class, create a property of type `List<ISpaceObject>` which can hold objects of any type that implements the interface.

Comment: Thank you both, I hope this isn't a really stupid question but what is object?

Comment: @LittleMissChaos The `Object` class is the base class that every other class is derived from (you can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object)). I wouldn't recommend creating a List<object> for the described situation. Stick with an interface and a class for each "space object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea on earth (pun intended) what all of those classes share in common. But whatever those are, may they be physical attributes would belong in some shared interface. The purpose would be to have shared method(s) that could be invoked. Remember an interface cannot have fields only public methods, expecting an implementation. For sake of simplicity, here's get and set.

```
interface ISolarSystem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Planet : ISolarSystem
{
    public int Radius { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     List<ISolarSystem> worldlyItems;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, if I use the var keyword will it know which one it is?

Comment: `var` can only be used with local variables.